# Is there any way to build a house in Blender and export it to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

Trying to make a game in Unity and I need a fairly complex house, i'm fairly experienced with Blender, and familiar with Unity, but mesh colliders don't work, convex or not, and making a bunch of differently-shaped colliders seems like a complex way to complete a simple task :/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make a video tutorial in regards of this.
Check this out [Blender to Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeZ918ppEDQ) if you have the spare time.

Cheers!

Comment: @OrigamiWithAlex No Worries! :)

Comment: If it worked, then i think you should mark this answer as accepted. This is the way of saying `Thank you!` on StackOverflow. Have a nice time!